# How to forward user back in case not pass the auth

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authorization, basic-authentication

I need to set auth on few pages and forward user back in case not authorized. For now, it display destination page with error.

```
Unauthorized
This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the 
document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., 
bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the 
credentials required.
```

I have 0 knowledges in basic auth and apache conf. I have google deep and didn't find any solution, please advice.

Thank you

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/en auth=1

AuthName "Please login to access english part"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/path/to/my/.htpasswd"

# first, allow everybody
Order Allow,Deny
Satisfy any
Allow from all
Require valid-user
# then, deny only if required
Deny from env=auth
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really a limitation of HTTP Basic Authentication.

However, you could customise the 401 response (which I assume is what you are seeing, as opposed to a 403) the server would otherwise send back. You could directly redirect from the custom 401, however, that would result in the client receiving a 3xx response, rather than a 401, which is not as informative and confusing for users. Or, you present a "friendly" message, with a link back to where they came from.

The additional problem is knowing which page to send the user back to. Unless you are storing this information in the session, then you'll need to examine the `Referer` HTTP request header, which might not be set at all.

For example... at the top of your `.htaccess` file, define your custom error document for the 401 response:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /errordocs/e401.php
```

In `/errordocs/e401.php`, you would have something like:

```
<?php
/**
 * 401 Unauthorized - Error Document
 */

// Get the HTTP Referer (if set at all)
$referer = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : null;

// Immediately redirect back to the referring page if known
// But the client then sees a 3xx response, without any error, which could be confusing for users
if (!empty($referer)) {
    header('Location: '.$referer,true,302);
    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>401 Unauthorized</h1>

<p>Sorry, you do not have permission to view that resource.</p>

<p>
<?php if (empty($referer)): ?>
    <a href="/">Go back to the home page</a>
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="<?=$referer?>">Go back to <?=$referer?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

To "automate" this, you could perhaps implement a meta refresh (or JS "redirect") back to the referring page (if set) after so many seconds.